# openlayers mouse position problem with css transform:scale()

Tags: css, transform, openlayers, openlayers-3

I need to scale my Openlayer layer map in order to display full map [ fit to screen ] while print preview is set [ A4, A3 ... A0 page setup ]. Now after apply the css `transform : scale()` to the map div the mouse over position is not working properly.

[image: map over postion after css scale()]

I found a **issues** in but didn't found any solution.
[ol issues #5747](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/5747)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But my situation was on "click query" and it goes to offset.

My solution is as follows. Hope it a little help.

```
 var px = evt.pixel[0]/0.8;
 var py = evt.pixel[1]/0.8;


 var geoPt = map.getCoordinateFromPixel([px,py]);

 var x = geoPt[0];
 var y = geoPt[1];
```